# AFNetworing - setImageWithURLRequest not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, afnetworking

I want to set tableview cell images in one of my apps. I use `AFNetworking (1.2.1)` and I do it with `setImageWithURLRequest`.

My code in which I set images looks like this:

```
    if (user.avatar) {
        NSString *imageUrl = user.avatar.url;

        [cell.profileImage setImageWithURLRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageUrl]] placeholderImage:nil success:^(NSURLRequest *request,   NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) {
            [cell setNeedsLayout];
        } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
        }];
    }
```

My error log returns this:

```
Error: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "The operation couldn’t be completed.   (NSURLErrorDomain error -999.)" UserInfo=0x1f5b56a0  {NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://d2rfichhc2fb9n.cloudfront.net/image/5/Cf7T_BA6- NFGL5ah0w4hdvmk_Vp7InMiOiJzMyIsImIiOiJhZG4tdXNlci1hc3NldHMiLCJrIjoiYXNzZXRzL3VzZXIvZTIvM2MvMjA vZTIzYzIwMDAwMDAwMDAwMC5qcGciLCJvIjoiIn0}
```

And the images dosn't get set. I didn't have this problem before I updated to `AFNetworking (1.2.1)`. Any ideas?

**Update**

Tried to strip the whitespace from the url like this:

```
NSString *imageUrl = [user.avatar.url stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
```

But I get the same error. And it could maybe be dangerous if the API sometime would contain a image file name that contains whitespaces.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I see three problems:

1. -999 means `NSURLErrorCancelled`, so it looks like the `URLRequest` gets cancelled somehow. Where is this code of yours? Is it possible that the `cell` object or the `UIImageView` `profileImage` is released prematurely?
2. More recent versions of AFNetworking require you to set the image yourself if you're defining a success block.
3. Make sure the URL is valid.

Try this (works when placed in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`):

```
__weak UITableViewCell *weakCell = cell;
[cell.imageView setImageWithURLRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageUrl]] placeholderImage:nil success:^(NSURLRequest *request,   NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) {
    if (weakCell)
    {
        weakCell.imageView.image = image;
        [weakCell setNeedsLayout];
    }
} failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked! Moved it to `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: Does this code creates retain cycle ?? I'm sure the block will retain cell, but  is cell retain the block ????

Comment: @NicHuang If you place this code in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` as suggested, if won't create any retain cycles. Also, the block will not retain the cell because of the `__weak` specifier.

Comment: I'm sorry! Let me put this in another way. If I don't use weakCell here, does  these code cause retain cycle?? If it does , why ?? Is cell.image retaining the block?? Does this has anything to do with tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:

Comment: @NicHuang The block will be retained by a `AFHTTPRequestOperation` and if you don't use `weakCell`, the cell will be retained by the block. This is not necessarily a problem here, but it's simply cleaner to not retain the cell. If the cell is already released when the `AFHTTPRequestOperation` completes, we don't need the image anymore anyway.

Answer (score 4):

There seem to be some extra space in your url

Your url is https://d2rfichhc2fb9n.cloudfront.net/image/5/Cf7T_BA6- NFGL5ah0w4hdvmk_Vp7InMiOiJzMyIsImIiOiJhZG4tdXNlci1hc3NldHMiLCJrIjoiYXNzZXRzL3VzZXIvZTIvM2MvMjA vZTIzYzIwMDAwMDAwMDAwMC5qcGciLCJvIjoiIn0

[Url Without Space](https://d2rfichhc2fb9n.cloudfront.net/image/5/Cf7T_BA6-NFGL5ah0w4hdvmk_Vp7InMiOiJzMyIsImIiOiJhZG4tdXNlci1hc3NldHMiLCJrIjoiYXNzZXRzL3VzZXIvZTIvM2MvMjAvZTIzYzIwMDAwMDAwMDAwMC5qcGciLCJvIjoiIn0)

Because of the extra space the image url is invalid and its not getting fetched.

**EDIT**

```
NSString *strCorrectUrl = [user.avatar.url stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" "
                                 withString:@""];
```

Comment: Tried to strip the whitespace, but it didn't help. See updated answer.